# sshd ignores match block

Tags: ssh, debian-squeeze

I have the problem that sshd somehow ignores a match block. The configuration of sshd is kind of basic. You can find it here: http://pastebin.com/bNUYhQnx

My goal is that every user except root should only be able to login with pubkey authentication.

But even with the configuration mentioned above I'm still able to login with a user which is not root only with a password.

Version of sshd is: OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze2, OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010

Can someone give me a hint what is missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting, I would have though this configuration would work, but I could reproduce it as well.
However, the other way around it worked fine for me:

```
PasswordAuthentication no

# other configuration (...)

Match User root
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

It looks like the not-operator does not behave like we would expect it would. Strange.

Comment: Yes this way it works for me, too. Thank you very much.